# Hide {{var comment}} when field empty in email

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, order-email, transactional-mail, variables

I'm creating **new order emails** for my company and need some help with the **variables**. I want to include an order comment in the email, but only if there actually is one. When the field is left empty at customer checkout, I still get this (yellow bar)...

[image]

How do I hide the row in the email when the field is left empty? If at all possible.

In the default emails it hides the row and the styling on when the field is left empty, and the code isn't that different.

Here's the code for the row in my email...

```
<tr align="center" style="background-color: #FFF0A3">
    <td width="650px" style="padding:8px; width:650px;">
        {{var comment}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{if comment}}
 {{var comment}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Upvoted in preference to my idea ;)